# MapStruct Property has no write accessor in MetaData for target name

Tags: kotlin, openapi, mapstruct, openapi-generator

I have a `FlatDTO` that needs to be mapped to a nested `Response` containing `InfoData` and `MetaData`

The code for the response is generated by `OpenAPI`. So the below definitions can't be changed.

```
package org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.openapi

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import javax.validation.Valid

data class Response(

    @field:Valid @field:JsonProperty("infoData", required = true) val infoData: InfoData,

    @field:Valid @field:JsonProperty("metaData", required = true) val metaData: MetaData
)


data class InfoData(

    @field:JsonProperty("id", required = true) val id: kotlin.String,

    )


data class MetaData(
    @field:JsonProperty("firstProperty") val firstProperty: String? = null,
)
```

I have defined `FlatDTO` as follows.

```
package org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.models

data class FlatDTO(
    var id: String? = null,
    var firstProperty: String,
)
```

Here is my mapper class which maps `FlatDTO` to `Response`

```
package org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.mapper

import org.mapstruct.Mapper
import org.mapstruct.Mapping
import org.mapstruct.Mappings
import org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.models.FlatDTO
import org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.openapi.Response

@Mapper
interface DataMapper {

    @Mappings(
        Mapping(target = "infoData.id", source = "id"),
        Mapping(target = "metaData.firstProperty", source = "firstProperty")
    )
    fun flatToResponse(flatDTO: FlatDTO): Response
}
```

When I try to build the code using `mvn clean install`
I get the following error.

```
error: Property "firstProperty" has no write accessor in MetaData for target name "metaData.firstProperty".
[ERROR]     @org.mapstruct.Mappings(value = {@org.mapstruct.Mapping(target = "infoData.id", source = "id"), @org.mapstruct.Mapping(target = "metaData.firstProperty", source = "firstProperty")})
```

I understand that this message is trying to say that there is no setter function for `firstProperty` because it's defined as `val` but that code cannot be edited. I can write my own custom mapper that works just fine.

I wanted to understand if there is a way to use `MapStruct` in this scenario.

Comment: figured it out?

Comment: @StefanHaberl The issue is open https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3088